# Upload Multiple Files With Multiple Fields And With media_handle_upload

Tags: uploads, media-library

I asked [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173197/upload-multiple-files-with-media-handle-upload) about few days ago and the answer solved my instantly problem but now when I tried to put many file fields in the form just the first field work because the solution of my previous question overwrite the $_FILES array.

Now I have the following HTML in my form:

```
<input type="file" name="my_file_upload[]" id="my_file_upload[]" multiple="multiple">
<input type="file" name="my_file_uploadone" id="my_file_uploadone">
<input type="file" name="my_file_uploadtwo[]" id="my_file_uploadtwo[]" multiple="multiple">
```

How can upload these files using media_handle_upload?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove the numbers my_file_upload1 to my_file_upload .

Comment: No problem I changed the names of the fields. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

code from my theme adjusted to you

```
<fieldset class="images">
<input type="file" name="my_file_upload[]" id="my_file_upload[]" multiple="multiple">
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="memes">
<input type="file" name="my_file_upload[]" id="my_file_upload[]" multiple="multiple">
</filedset>
```

and its working

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have many fields that doesn't contain `[]` at the end of their names for example the featured image field and in another form the avatar image field and with different names.

Comment: did you try it and didnt work ?

Comment: Yes with different names and in my case I test it and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I found it and its work great for me, I used the solution in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45188/front-end-post-with-multiple-upload-images) to solve my problem but I'll not chose my answer as a correct answer because the solution in that question uses this function [`media_handle_sideload`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload), even if WordPress codex told that this function work like the `media_handle_upload` function. but I'll wait until someone give me the answer that used `media_handle_upload` function.

If no one gave me the answer then I'll select my answer.